# ActiveSupport::Callbacks method missing. Can't find method options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback, activesupport

I would like to know how to move to rails 4.2 from rails 3.14

For now I try to find method `options` in `ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback`

This method exists in ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback version 3.0.9, but it doesn't exists in recent version 4.2

After activesupport/* library investigation in rvm catalog, I have found method `normalize_callback_params` which returns `type, filters, options` but this doesn't help me to pass tests in my app.

However, I have found interesting property in ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback : if-property. It returns bool expression for this callback, so, my test could be rewritten with it.

```
    it 'should apply filter options' do
        klass.unjsonify_param :param_name, { only: [:create, :update] }
        filters = klass._process_action_callbacks
        puts "this is filters methods #{filters.class.instance_methods.sort - Array.instance_methods}"
        filter = filters.find { |f| f.filter == :unjsonify_param_name }
        puts "this is filter methods: #{filter.class.instance_methods.sort - Object.instance_methods}"
        puts "this is filter: #{filter.instance_values}"
        # fail here, method `options` doesn't exists for ActiveSupport::Callbacks::Callback::<instance_hash>       
        expect(filter.options[:only]).to be == [:create, :update]
      end
```

Could anyone helps me to understand new activesupport callbacks architecture to migrate from old rails version to new one.